# where does the discrepancy between \# in PS1 and n in !n come from?

Tags: history, ps1

Something has been gnawing at me for a while now and I can't seem to find a relevant answer either in man pages or using your 'Don't be evil' search engine.

My .bashrc has the following:

```
shopt -s histappend
HISTSIZE=100
HISTFILESIZE=0   # 200 previous value
```

Putting HISTFILESIZE to 0 allows me to start with a clean history slate with each new term window.

I find it practical in conjunction with using a prompt that contains `\#`, because when visualizing a previous command before recalling it with `!n` or `!-p`, one can just do:

```
$ history | more
```

to see its relevant "n" value

In my case, usually the result of:

```
$ \history | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'   # (I know this is an overkill, don't flame me)
```

equals the expanded value of # in PS1 minus 1, which is how I like it to be at all times.
But then, sometimes not. At times the expanded value of # sort of "runs away". It's incremented in such a a manner that it becomes > than

```
$(( $(\history | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}')+1 ))
```

Any pointers, anyone?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Terdon. Was just doing that myself, when you submitted yours.

Comment: Can you give us an example of when this happens? Also, what's the output of `echo $HISTCONTROL`? Does it only happen when you run the same command twice? Can it be with any command? Also, while this shouldn't cause any problems as such, there's no point  in using the `histappend` option if you have your history file size set to 0.

Comment: Right on terdon ! My $HISTCONTROL is set to "ignoreboth". I should have thought about that, in conjunction with my use of \# in my prompt. I'd better use \! in PS1 in that case, because I do want "ignoreboth" on. Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likeliest reason for this is that you've set `HISTCONTROL` to a value that includes `ignoredupes`. Test by running

```
echo $HISTCONTROL
```

If that returns something like `ignoredups`, this means that duplicate commands are not saved to your history. They *are* however counted by PS1's `\#`. This means that `\#` will happily increment each time you run the same command twice but your `history` will not increase and this will lead to the discrepancy you observe.

So, either remove the `ignoredupes` from `HISTCONTROL` (this is usually set in your `~/.profile` but can also be set in `~/.bashrc`) or use [`\!`](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-prompt.html) instead of `\#` in `PS1`.

Comment: ok. question solved. solution is in my comment as a response to your initial comment Terdon. Your original comment mentioning $HISTCONTROL did it.